# what's wrong with my code(android programming)

Tags: android, storage

I am trying to add the contents of a text file to a content box in my app. When I give the name of the .txt file, the contents of the txt file should get placed in my content box. This txt file is placed in the sdcard directory.

Here is the code I have written

```
public void sdd(View v){

    TextView t = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    EditText content = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtContent);
    File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String tt=".txt";
   // File file = new File(dir,"text.txt");
    File file = new File(dir,t.getText().toString()+ tt);
    if(file.exists())   // check if file exist
    {
          //Read text from file
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            //You'll need to add proper error handling here
        }
        //Set the text
      //  et.setText(text);
        content.setText(text);
    }
    else
    {
        content.setText("Sorry file doesn't exist!!");
    }
 }
```

Now, when I am trying to give the file name, I am always getting `Sorry file doesn't exist`, even though it does! Can anyone tell me what's wrong? Or how to improve this code

Comment: What is your problem? be specific what you want to do?

Comment: have u take all permission dude

Comment: i have two text box in my app. The first one, we enter the name of the text file. As soon as the user enters the name, i want the contents of that text file to be pasted in my content box. Now, when i'm giving the name of the text file, it's saying file doesn't exist, even though it does!

Comment: yes, i have taken all permissions

Comment: String filename = getText().toString()+ tt; then use filename.trim() , may be some unwanted space in that string

Comment: @BhanuSharma importing the name form the editText is the likely culprit; could get control characters or white space.  I'd trim before adding the extension, but good idea.

Comment: @BhanuSharma can you please write the code for that?

Comment: @AspiringAndroidDev see my ans dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to check `File` like this:

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String filename = t.getText().toString()+ tt;
File file = new File(dir,filename.trim());

if(file.exists() && (file.length()!=0))   // check if file exist
{

//do your job

}else{

 content.setText("Sorry file doesn't exist!!");

}
```

And add Read and Write permission in `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Take permission both read and write at this time u only need read permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

May be some blank space have a prob then try wd this

```
TextView t = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    EditText content = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtContent);
    File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String tt=".txt";

String filename = getText().toString()+ tt; 


    File file = new File(dir,filename.trim());
```

remaining code is same

Comment: prob wd blnk space i think i mention it in comment it self i suppose that u got it from there only but ohk good u solved it

Answer (score 0):

I'm just starting out with Android dev too!

First I'd create a new variable to store this: t.getText().toString()+ tt

Then I'd trying debugging your code. Set a breakpoint at the line where you test for file existence, that's clearly returning false.

Check the content of that variable to be sure it's got the filename you're expecting

Hope that helps!